# how to calculate the percentage of property prices in relation to the total amount of property prices in sql?

Tags: sql, pgadmin-4

how to calculate the percentage of property prices in relation to the total amount of property prices in sql?

I took the property state price and divide it by the total prices of all states. I am a new in sql. I am just figuring it out. thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and share some simple data and the expected output, and also share with us what have you tried

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking something like this:

```
SELECT property_name, price, (price / total_price) * 100 AS percentage
FROM your_table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(price) AS total_price FROM your_table) AS t;
```